# 1D-diffusion equation on the half-plane.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I was wondering how I can determine an integral expression that accounts for $x<0$ for the diffusion equation on the half-plane governed by the PDE

$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2}$ over $0<x<\infty$ for $t>0$.

My initial condition is $C(x,0)=0$ for all $x\ge0$. I have another condition of $C(0,t)=C_0$.
My thoughts on approaching this is to take an even extension, however in lectures an even extension was only shown when we have $C(x,0)=f(x)$. What should I do for when my condition equals $0$? 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the conditions correct?  $C(x,0)=0$ for $x\ge 0$, and $C(0,t) = C_0$ seem inconsistent to me unless $C_0=0$.

Comment: Yeah they are correct, that's why I am confused on how to proceed. We are told an initial concentration of pollutant is $C_0$ and $C_0$ is a constant. If you like, I can comment the entire question for clarity?

Comment: I'm wondering whether or not since $C(0,t)=C_0$, then that means $\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}(0,t)=0$, is that something we could deduce? Since $C_0$ is a constant? This would also preserve the boundary condition at $x=0$.

Comment: OK.  I'm confused though.  If $C(x,0)=0$ at $x=0$, then $C(0,0)=0$.  And if $C(0,t)=C_0$ with no restriction on time, then $C(0,0)=C_0$.  Therefore $C_0$ must be zero.  If this is for a class, I would ask your instructor to clarify.

Comment: Okay so my conditions are the following, for clarity.

$C(x,0)=0$ for all $x\ge0$. Once $t>0$ then we have $C(0,t)=C_0$. We also have $C(x,t)→0$ as $x→\infty$

Comment: I just don't know how to deal with $C(x,0)=0$ for all $x\ge0$.

Comment: You need to understand that the mathematical condition you use is determined by the *physical boundary conditions*, either reflective (even extension) or absorbing (odd extension).  You have to know which of those you are asked to deal with.  The thing that bugs me is that this is not spelled out here.  I *infer* that you are supposed to use reflective boundary conditions (even extension) because, for absorbing BCs, $(0,)$ would have to be zero.  It apparently isn't, so I *infer* that you have reflective BCs and you need an even extenstion.  Seriously, I would get my instructor to clarify.